# Is torsion-free equivalent to free for non-finitely generated modules over a PID?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Maybe this is a trivial question. If $A$ is a PID and $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, it's well known that $M$ is torsion-free iff $M$ is free.

However, if $M$ is not finitely generated, does the result still hold? I think that the answer is no, simply because I could't find it in any reference.

If the answer is negative, please, show a counter-example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A counterexample is $\mathbb{Q}$ considered as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Definitely torsion-free but not free.

Comment: Or to stay in the general context: Any non-trivial localisation of $A$ is torsion-free, but not free.

Comment: @MooS Do you know if your statement still true for $A$ not a PID?

Comment: It is still true if $A$ is an integral domain. Localisations of an integral domain $A$ are essential extensions of $A$. Such an extension cannot contain $A$ as a direct summand, hence cannot be free. The torsion-freeness is clear I think.

Comment: If you do not know the concept of essential extensions, we can do it in a very elementary way: Any two elements of $S^{-1}A$ fulfill a $A$-relation (by clearing denominators), hence if $S^{-1}A$ would be free, it would be free of rank $1$. It is easy to show that this is not the case, if the localisation is non-trivial.

Comment: @MooS Sorry, but what argument are you thinking when you said  that if $A \hookrightarrow S^{-1} A$ is an essential extension, then $A$ cannot be a direct summand?

Comment: @MooS Furthermore there something strange about your comment, if $A \hookrightarrow S^{-1} A$ is essential, then  every $a/ 1 \in S^{-1} A$ must satisfy $xa \not\in A$ for some $x \in A$. Otherwise $(a/ 1)$ (the cyclic module generated by $a/1$) intersects $A$.